# If statement vs Switch statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, switch-statement

I have tried out both switch and if statements on my code. Switch looks better imo. But it doesnt work for me. The if statement works tho. Can you see the problem? I feel like they are doing the same thing.  (im filtering a list of objects)

```
let sort = {};


//THE IF STATEMENT
if (query.order == 'name_asc') {
        sort = {name : 1 }
     }
     if (query.order == 'name_desc') {
         sort = { name : -1 }
     }
     if ( query.order == 'lowprice') {
         sort = { price : 1 }
     }
     if ( query.order == 'oldest' ) {
         sort = { year : 1 }
     }
     if ( query.order == 'newest' ) {
         sort = { year : -1 }
     }

// THE SWITCH STATEMENT

     switch (query.order) {
        case query.order == 'name_asc':
            sort = { name : 1 }
            console.log(1)
            break;

        case query.order == 'name_desc':
            sort = { name : -1 }
            console.log(2)
            break;

        case query.order == 'lowprice':
            sort = { price : 1 }
            console.log(3)
            break;

        case query.order == 'oldest':
            sort = { year : 1 }
            console.log(4)
            break;
     
        case query.order == 'newest':
            sort = { price : -1 }
            console.log(5)
            break;
        default: console.log(6)
        break;
     }
```

Comment: remove `query.order == ` in the `case` ... so `case 'name_asc'` etc - here's some [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) to learn how to use switch

Comment: Thanks, tried case  == 'name_asc': first. Now i know how to use it properly:)

Comment: `case == 'name_asc'` no, that too is wrong, it should be just like I said, not something you made up

Comment: Lol i know. I just said i tried it xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the switch statement wrong `query.order == 'name_asc` ect. evaluate to a boolean. Therefore the switch statement attempts to compare the string to a boolean value which results in never entering the case statements.

The correct use would be

```js
switch (query.order) {
        case 'name_asc':
            sort = { name : 1 }
            console.log(1)
            break;

        case 'name_desc':
            sort = { name : -1 }
            console.log(2)
            break;

        case 'lowprice':
            sort = { price : 1 }
            console.log(3)
            break;

        case 'oldest':
            sort = { year : 1 }
            console.log(4)
            break;
     
        case 'newest':
            sort = { year : -1 }
            console.log(5)
            break;
        default: console.log(6)
        break;
     }
```

However I would recommend to use an Object to map the entry value to the result. This is up to you of course.

```js
const NAME_ASC = 'name_asc';
const NAME_DESC = 'name_desc';
const PRICE_LOW = 'lowprice';
const PRICE_HIGH = 'highprice';
const CREATION_ASC = 'oldest';
const CREATION_DESC = 'newest';

const sortOrderMapping = {
   [NAME_ASC]: {name: 1},
   [NAME_DESC]: {name: -1},
   // fill in all the cases
}


function getSortOrderObject(orderEnum){
   // this returns undefined if orderEnum is not a valid value
   // maybe you want to return a default value, throw an error, or utilize Option monads
   return sortOrderMapping[orderEnum];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript the syntax of the [`switch`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp) statement is:

```
switch(expression) {
  case x:
    // code block
    break;
  case y:
    // code block
    break;
  default:
    // code block
}
```

So you should remove the `query.order ==` from your `case`, *e.g.*:

```js
function get_sort(query_order) {
  switch (query_order) {
    case 'name_asc': return {name: 1};
    case 'name_desc': return {name: -1};
    case 'lowprice': return {price: 1};
    case 'oldest': return {year: 1};
    case 'newest': return {year: -1};
  }
}
['name_asc', 'name_desc', 'lowprice', 'oldest', 'newest'].forEach(query_order => {
  console.log(get_sort(query_order));
});
```